# Unique Constraint Not Working with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, unique-constraint, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.2.6 and I have two entities `Profile` and `Category`. Each `Category` will have `ProfileId` to identify to which `Profile` it belongs. I'm trying to enforce uniqueness for `Name` and `ProfileId` in `Category`. But however my unique constraint fails.

Here is my Entities,

**BaseEntity:**

```cs
public class BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? ModifiedAt { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

**Profile:**

```cs
public class Profile : BaseEntity<Guid>, IAggregateRoot
{
    private Profile()
    {
        // required by EF
    }

    public Profile(string brandName)
    {
        Guard.Against.NullOrEmpty(brandName, nameof(brandName));
        BrandName = brandName;
    }

    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

**Category:**

```cs
public class Category : BaseEntity<Guid>, IAggregateRoot
{
    private Category()
    {
        // required by EF
    }

    public Category(string name)
    {
        Guard.Against.NullOrEmpty(name, nameof(name));
        Name = name;
    }

    public Category(string name, string code) : this(name)
    {
        Guard.Against.NullOrEmpty(code, nameof(code));

        Code = code;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }
}
```

**Category Entity Configuration:**

```cs
public class CategoryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Category> builder)
    {
        builder.HasAlternateKey(c => new { c.ProfileId, c.Name });
        // builder.HasIndex(c => new { c.ProfileId, c.Name }).IsUnique();

        builder.Property(c => c.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        builder.Property(c => c.Code)
            .HasMaxLength(10);

        builder.HasOne<Profile>()
             .WithMany()
             .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProfileId)
             .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

I tried `builder.HasAlternateKey(c => new { c.ProfileId, c.Name });` and `builder.HasIndex(c => new { c.ProfileId, c.Name }).IsUnique();`. But both doesn't seem to work. Please can you assist on where I go wrong?

Comment: `builder.HasIndex(c => new { c.ProfileId, c.Name }).IsUnique();` is all you need. What is not working? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: I tried `builder.HasIndex(c => new { c.ProfileId, c.Name }).IsUnique();` before posting the question. I'm able to add two `Category` entity with same `ProfileId` and `Name`. Uniqueness is breaking here right?

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean anything. Did you migrate afterwards? Is EF responsible for creating the database at all? (i.e. is it an existing database?) What does the actual table definition look like? Also, not all databases support unique indexes, especially unique together. For example, the in-memory provider will not care. I don't think SQLite does either, and any NoSQL stores like CosmosDB will not pay attention to it.

Comment: At the end of the day, it's a database-level constraint, enforced only if the particular database actually support it. Even then, the op will simply throw an exception, which you'll need to catch and then recover from somehow. Long and short, you should really enforce this yourself via a validation layer, and not depend on the database. The unique index is mostly to maintain DB consistency should something fall through the cracks; it's not and shouldn't be your first line of defense.

Comment: I'm trying with in-memory provider as of now. As you mentioned that's the reason it's  now working now I guess. I'll try to migrate and post an update. And if I should not depend on database then do I need to check for uniqueness in code by querying and then do a insert?

Comment: Yes. That should be part of your model validation.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be an in-memory limitation. The real DB would throw an error.